# How do I loop through divs and find the nearest span and add different things to each span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example say I had the following HTML:

```
<div class="div-style">div text</div> <span>span text</span>
<div class="div-style">another div</div> <span>another span</span>
<div class="div-style">hello</div> <span>world</span>
```

Now what I want to do is: (using jQuery)

1. Go to each `<div>` with the class 'div-style'
2. Find the following `<span>`
3. Append the current `<span>`'s text to the span (in effect repeating the span text within the span text, so the first span would display 'span textspan text')

Comment: try `$('.div-style').each(function(){
var t = $(this).next('span').text();

$(this).next('span').text($(this).next('span').text() + t);


})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.div-style').each(function(){
var t = $(this).next('span').text();

$(this).next('span').text($(this).next('span').text() + t);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-style">div text</div> <span>span text</span>
<div class="div-style">another div</div> <span>another span</span>
<div class="div-style">hello</div> <span>world</span>
```

Try this

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/rg9zanks/

```
$('.div-style + span').each(function() {
  var span = $(this)
  span.after('<span>' + span.text() + '</span>')
})
```

You can take advantage of the `+` selector to avoid using the `.next()` function.

1. Select spans that follow elements with the class `.div-style`
2. Loop through using `.each()`, create a new span after the selected spans using `after()`, and populate it with the same text using `.text()`.

Comment: Nice work with the adjacent sibling selector. I've given you an upvote for reminding me to use it instead of `.next()` (and for not complaining when I edited it into my existing answer).

Comment: @nnnnnn alls fair when going for that sweet sweet rep :p

Comment: Well...normally I try not to let other answers influence me (though I do skim earlier ones to double-check that I haven't posted a duplicate), but in this case I figure the key part of my answer is the use of `.html()`'s implict looping, so adding in the `+` was just a bonus.

Answer (score 3):

Literally a one-liner with jQuery, a little something like this:

```js
$(".div-style + span").html(function(i,v) { return v + v; });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-style">div text</div> <span>span text</span>
<div class="div-style">another div</div> <span>another span</span>
<div class="div-style">hello</div> <span>world</span>
```

Further reading:

- [The `+` next sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)
- [Passing a function to the `.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) (or you could use the `.text()` method instead)

Comment: hehe you adoped my `+` sign. I guess you learned something too :p. I'll give you an upvote for showing me you can pass a function to the `.html()` method.

Comment: @AR7 - Yeah, thanks dude. You reminded of something I already knew but never seem to remember to use. Certainly makes the answer neater than using `.next()`, especially when I was obviously shooting for short. Many jQuery methods let you pass a function in that way (`.text()`, `.css()`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.div-style').each(function(i, node){
   var nextSpan = $(node).next();
   nextSpan.append(nextSpan.html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-style">div text</div> <span>span text</span>
<div class="div-style">another div</div> <span>another span</span>
<div class="div-style">hello</div> <span>world</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
   $("div.div-style").next('span').each(function () {
      $(this).append($(this).text());
   });

});
```